# Redirect standard input/output between threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm creating a GUI that needs to communicate with a C++ engine via stdin (sending commands) and read its stdout (read engine response). I'm doing this in an iOS environment so I can't fork the process and communicate between them but I can create  new threads which I think should work just fine.

I've looked at other questions similar to this one but they mostly utilize process forking via `fork()` which I can't use. Is it a similar method when dealing with threads?

Is there something in C++ that can facilitate inter-thread communication via standard input/output? Or should look into C functions (e.g. `pthread_create` and `dup2`)?

Edit: It was pointed out that my question is an XY problem, so for more clarification on the source problem: The C++ engine is a chess game engine that runs via a command line interface normally. You interact with it (i.e. input moves) via standard input in a CLI. I'm packaging it in an iOS app which cant do that (no forking or terminal access) so I'm trying to programmatically simulate stdin to the engine's main loop where it listens for user input via stdin.

Comment: _"facilitate inter-thread communication via standard input/output?"_ Why would you want that? There are better ways threads can communicate with each other.

Comment: @TheDude the c++ engine is listening for input via standard input since you normally interact with it via command line but I can't do that in iOS env.

Comment: And what does that have to do with threads?

Comment: @TheDude I want to run the engine in a separate thread so I can simulate standard input to it as per [this recommendation](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/19787/15690). The engine runs on a loop so I need it separate from the main UI thread

Comment: [Sounds like an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do? What is the C++ engine used for? Sounds like you're asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual issue.

Comment: @Myst Sorry about that. The C++ engine is a chess game engine that runs via a command line interface normally. You interact with it (i.e. input moves) via standard input in a CLI. I'm packaging it in an iOS app which cant do that (no forking or terminal access) so I'm trying to programmatically simulate stdin to the engine's main loop where it listens for user input via stdin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An old school Unix way to redirect stdin/stdout to pipes is to:

```
close(0);
close(1);
int io[2];
if(pipe(io))
   perror("ERROR, blah blah");
```

Explanation:

The Unix OS promises to attach new file descriptors to the lowest available file descriptor available (which is an array starting at index 0 up to the maximum allocated size for the process).

By closing stdin (0) and stdout(1), these file descriptors become available.

By opening a pipe, these file descriptors (0 and 1) are attached to the new pipe.

Anything that was referencing these two fie descriptors is now referencing the new pipe.

Comment: Interesting, so does this bypass a need for any sort of inter-thread communication? If I'm understanding this correctly, the thread that I want to redirect standard input to need only read off the read fd end of `io` once (like a normal pipe?) So the main thread could `printf` something to standard out and then the other thread would read it off the io pipe

Comment: @swigganicks Yes. I think the general rule might be adjusted when accommodating either non-blocking IO or larger payloads (as pipes have a limit to their buffers, so `read` might be signaled or polled), but the general rule is that the pipes *are* the inter-process (or inter-thread) communication. No need for anything else.